# Extracting all rows based on a value of cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking to list all the values of a cell that match the criteria.

My first **Sheet 1** contains the data (refer screenshot), will have 3 columns A, B & C, and nearly 12,000+ rows.

[image]

In **Sheet 2**,  I need to pull the data based on section (refer screenshot).

[image]

I tried with **VLOOKUP**; however, that stops at the first occurrence.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: First found row may use single VLOOKUP over whole table. But all the next must use VLOOKUP over a part of table from the source row referenced in prev. result row + 1 till the data end (and this needs in each source row to be unique). I think the formula will be too complex, and I'd recommend VBA macro which fires by `result!E2` change and copies all matched rows from source.

Comment: It wouldn't be THAT complex. I've written answers on here before that do that exact thing. @Vasishta, what's the maximum number of appearances of a single HSN/SAC code?

Comment: Around 25 to 30

Comment: You can use the `Advanced Filter`.  If it needs to update automatically, you might need program a `Worksheet_Activate` metod.